# API Explorer Customer Retrieve All Request Body

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Using IPP's API Explorer (V2 QBO), I was trying to test the "Retrieve all" call for Customers.  In the documentation it says that you can put the following in the request body in order to override the default of 10 customers per page:

PageNum=1
    ResultsPerPage=20

However, when I click "Try it!", it doesn't like it, giving the following results

```
<FaultInfo xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/baseexceptionmodel/xsd">
  <Message>Unauthorized OAuth Token: signature_invalid</Message>
  <ErrorCode>401</ErrorCode>
  <Cause>SERVER</Cause>
</FaultInfo>
```

What am I doing wrong, and were can I find documentation on the specific syntax to use?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to use some other restclients (like RestClient plugin in Mozilla or Fiddler). It seems, there is a bug in apiexploer.

PFB details.

Essential Req header -

```
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
OAuth Tokens - You can get these from ApiExploer
```

Post Body format -

```
PageNum=1&ResultsPerPage=3
```

[image]

Doc Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online/0100_calling_data_services/0030_retrieving_objects#Paging

Please let me know if it works for you.

Thanks

Comment: Manas, Thank you for the clarification.  I downloaded fiddler and attempted to "compose" the request, but it complains about the signature.  Not sure how to determine what the value for oauth_signature should be.

Comment: You have to add an OAuth plugin/addon to fiddler and there you need to pass consumer key, consumer secret, access key and access secret and . I don't have a quick ref of that (but I'll share it if I find it).
In the mean time, you can add RestClient plugin to your mozilla browser. It will work fine. I had used mozilla to test this use case. let me know if you find any issue related to this.

Comment: Unable to find an oauth plugin for fiddler, but was able to download restclient for Firefox. Did not find any instructions, but discerned how to create authentication request header and context-type header, url and body.  However, sending this, I received a "500 internal server error".  Not sure about some settings offered - like "Auto" checkboxes on oAuth Nonce and oAuth Timestamp.

Comment: Are you calling the following API to get the BASE URL corresponding to your company's relam and using the same to construct the Customer endpoint ?
If not, PFB links
Base URL -https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online/0100_calling_data_services/0010_getting_the_base_url#Getting_the_Base_URL_at_Runtime

Customer endpoint - URL: <baseURL>/resource/customer/v2/<realmID>
Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online/customer#Creating_a_Customer

Please let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change anything from the 'OAuth Setting' tab. You can enter only the four OAuth keys and click insert. Please click the small arrow beside 'Insert' button to enable auto-refresh flag and click the remember setting checkbox(Otherwise after every API call you need to open this window and need to click refresh button in a popup).

[image]